# Windshield leak

Tags: windshield, water-leak

I appear to have a leak near the upper right hand corner of my passenger side windshield. At least that my guess. The leak was really only noticeable whilst driving down the road into heavy rain. Can/should I fix this myself? what should I use?

Answer (score 1):

The areas for checking the leak are the window channels, the grooves which the glass slides in, are fully in place to the top of the window frame; The glass is sitting in the window channels squarely, adjustment can usually be made on the glass retainers behind the doors trim panel; The door aperture seal is correctly fitted and in good condition, the aperture seal is the usually rubber tube like affair fitted to the door aperature and which the door closes against.

Answer (score 1):

Another area to pay attention to is if you have a sun/moon roof installed in your vehicle. These have drain tubes which can come loose and allow leakage inside the vehicle in odd places. You'd probably need to remove the sun roof to figure out if this has happened. I would not suggest you try it if you've never done it before, as a small leak is much better in the short term than a large hole.